# Is there any way to disable keyPressEvent temporarily?

Tags: qt, events

I reimplement `keyPressEvent` function in my widget.

I want to disable key press while doing some works in `keyPressEvent` function like this:

```
void TrackingForm::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
   // disable get keyPress
   doWork();
   // enable 
}
```

the other way is clear buffer of events posted (queueded events). I use `QApplication::removePostedEvents` in `keyPressEvent` function but it does not work:

```
void TrackingForm::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
   doWork(); // this function takes about 3 seconds
   QApplication::removePostedEvents(this);
}
```

Can someone help me?
thanks a lot

Comment: If your `doWork()` works in the same thread, I assume that no other events will be processed until the `doWork()` exits.

Comment: You could install an event filter and then remove it. You would still get the events though. I do not think you should manually mess with manipulating the event loop.

Comment: yes, it is , but if you press some key 5 time while doWork work, then after finished process of doWork , the keyPressEvent called 5 time. i want to prevent it.

Comment: @user2262941, you could try to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents)` after your `doWork()` function exit to process all pending events except keyPress etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to execute `doWork()` in a separate thread - then you could just ignore events in `keyPressEvent()` while `doWork()` is running...

For example you could try this:

```
void TrackingForm::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (!workInProgress) //workInProgress is a bool member
        QtConcurrent::run(doWork);
        //doWork() sets workInProgress to true before work,
        //and to false after work is done
    else
        event->ignore();
}
```